# Laravel 4 & Pagoda: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web-deployment, pagoda-box

So, my app is on [this link](http://mammoth-meghann.gopagoda.com/)

I am able to create a tunnel using Pagoda client and I can view databases via the mySQL CLI.
That command being `mysql -u<DBusername> -p<DBpassword> -htunnel.pagodabox.com -P<the port tunnel shows me to connect on e.g. 3306>`

The app works locally. Okay, further i've searched and searched, did the **app/database.php** configuration, checked the socket, it's okay too, at **/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock** .

The **error** is this:
In my **Boxfile**, I have this before-deploy hook `before_deploy:
        - "php artisan migrate:install --env=production"`

This causes the [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory and hence it isn't deployed.

Any help\reference would be really welcome. Any more info can be given too. Cheers!

Comment: Not even a comment? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the mysql configuration in my `app/config/database.php` to this:

`'host'         => isset($_SERVER['DB1_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_HOST'] : '127.0.0.1',
'database'    => isset($_SERVER['DB1_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_NAME'] : '<db_name>',
'username'    => isset($_SERVER['DB1_USER']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_USER'] : '<mysql_username>',
'password'    => isset($_SERVER['DB1_PASS']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_PASS'] : '<mysql_password>',`

That solved my problem!

Comment: Thank you very much Farhat Baji!